# I'm getting this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: c, matrix

I need help here! I'm trying to code a console-based C program which solves several systems of equations.

**Exercise:**

The program receives an entry file (input and output file names typed in by the user), containing n, m, and a bunch of numbers which will fill in a matrix. This matrix is an extended matrix which has n rows and n+m columns (where m is the number of systems to solve). First "submatrix" nxn must be reduced using Gauss Elimination method with pivoting.

This is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int gauss_pivot (double **a, int n, int m, double tol);

    void resol (double **a, int n, int m);

    int main(void) {

        double **ampliada;
        int n, m;
        int i, j;
        FILE *entrada, *sortida;
        char nomE[31], nomS[31];

        printf("Noms dels fitxers d'entrada i sortida\n");
        scanf("%s %s", nomE, nomS);

        entrada = fopen(nomE, "r");
        sortida = fopen(nomS, "w");

        if (entrada == NULL || sortida == NULL){
            if (entrada == NULL){
                printf("Error en el fitxer d'entrada\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                printf("Error en el fitxer de sortida\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        fscanf(entrada, "%d", &n);
        fscanf(entrada, "%d", &m);

        ampliada = (double**)malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
        if (ampliada == NULL) {
            printf("Memòria insuficient\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            ampliada[i] = (double*)malloc(m*sizeof(double));
            if (ampliada[i] == NULL){
                printf("Memòria insuficient\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            for (j=0; j<=m; j++){
                fscanf(entrada, "%le", &ampliada[i][j]);
            }
        }

        gauss_pivot(ampliada, n, m, 10^(-16));

        resol(ampliada, n, m);

        return 0;
    }

    int gauss_pivot (double **a, int n, int m, double tol){

        float q;
        double pivot, aux;
        int r;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            pivot = 0;
            for (r = j; r < n; r++){
                if (fabs(a[r][j]) > pivot){
                    pivot = a[r][j];
                }
            }
            if (pivot != a[j][j]){
                for (int s = 0; s < (n+m); s++){
                    aux = a[r][s];
                    a[r][s] = a[j][s];
                    a[j][s] = aux;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(i > j){
                    q = a[i][j]/a[j][j];
                    for (int k = 0; k < (n+m); k++){
                        a[i][k] = a[i][k] - q*a[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void resol (double **a, int n, int m){

        double resultats[n], suma;

        for (int s = 1; s <= m; s++){
            printf("Solució al sistema %d:\n", s);

            resultats[n]=a[n][n+1]/a[n][n];
            for(int i = n-1; i >= 1; i--){
                suma=0;
                for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++){
                    suma=suma+a[i][j]*resultats[j];
                }
                resultats[i]=(a[i][n+1]-suma)/a[i][i];
            }

            for (int r = 1; r <= n; r++){
                printf("X_%d = %f", r, resultats[r]);
            }

        }
    }
```

It crashes on the following lines (sometimes one, somtimes the other):

```
                    aux = a[r][s];
                    a[r][s] = a[j][s];
                    a[j][s] = aux;
```

And I get the following error message:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You allocate `n` or `m` elements of `double` but then index by `s`, which is `m + n`...

Comment: note that `r` is equal to `n` following the loop `for (r = j; r < n; r++)`, which is (also) out of bounds when accessing `aux = a[r][s];`

Comment: If the matrix is of size nxm, then in the loop `for (int s = 0; s < (n+m); s++)` variable `s` may never be larger than `m-1`.

Comment: `j<=m;` --> `j < m;`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie true, matrix is in fact n x n+m, i edited the information, i should still replace "n+m" with "n+m-1"

Comment: @BLUEPIXY True, I constantly go out of bounds, thanks!

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @MichaelWalz "The program receives an entry file (input and output file names typed in by the user), containing n, m, and a bunch of numbers which will fill in a matrix."

Comment: @Adria What I meant is you should provide an example of input that triggers the problem. It's just to help us to reproduce the problem without needing to guess.

Comment: @MichaelWalz This is the input file I tried, I guess it's fine https://imgur.com/a/KVoAP

Comment: @Adria pleeease in the future don't post pictures of text but [edit] your question and paste text _there_ as text.